# Qt - Chinese rendered as empty boxes even when fall back font is available

Tags: qt, fonts

I'm using Qt 5.4.3.

In my app `main()`, I call `QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("path_to_zen_hei")` and `QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("path_to_open_sans")`.  When I query my QFontDatabase families, Open Sans & WenQuanYi Zen Hei fonts families are both available.  So far so good!

If I start my application with `QApplication::setFont("Open Sans", 12)`, I get the Latin alphabet rendered beautifully and Chinese characters all render as blank boxes.  If I start my application with `QApplication::setFont("WenQuanYi Zen Hei", 12)` Chinese characters render just fine and the Latin alphabet looks awful.

What I want is to use Open Sans all the time but when called upon to render Chinese characters (which are not available in Open Sans), to fall back on the Zen Hei font to render them.

My question is, what am I missing here - with both fonts installed as application fonts and the application font set to Open Sans, why doesn't Qt fall back on Zen Hei for rendering Chinese glyphs instead of displaying blank boxes?